# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'cycle' in Wordpress Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-cycle

I don't know why I'm getting this error, I've added in the head the jquery library (1.7.1) and in the footer the cycle plugin and my custom code.

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/sliders/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/general.js"></script>
```

Inside general.js I have the following:

```
if($('.testimonials').length) {
    function onAfter(curr, next, opts, fwd) {
        var $ht = $(this).height();
        $(this).parent().animate({height: $ht});
    }
    $('#testimonial-slider').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        timeout: 8000,
        height: 'auto',
        pause: 1,
        before: onAfter,
        cleartypeNoBg: true
    });
}
```

I've even tried to just wrap that in a `<script></script>` tag just incase there was something else in `general.js` that was breaking it, but I've had no luck...

This is for a wordpress website and I don't know why it's happening...

Comment: Did you remove WordPress default jQuery library? It's built-in...

Comment: @elclanrs how do you remove it?

Comment: shouldnt $ be jQuery ?

Comment: @wordpresser I got `jQuery.document(function($) { //stuff });` in my code, but I've fixed it now, it was the conflicting jQuery libraries!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by removing the default jQuery library as indicated by eclanrs